# node.js , ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code :

```
app.get("/posts/:slug", function(request, response) {

    var slug = request.params.slug;

    connection.query("SELECT * from `posts` WHERE slug = ?", [ slug ], function(err, rows) {
        var post = rows[];
        response.render("post", { post: post, formatDate: formatDate });
    });

});
```

When I run `index.js` in terminal ;

```
/home/yasser/yasser/index.js:33
    var post = rows[];
                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
```

Comment: This isn't valid Javascript syntax: `var post = rows[];`.  So, what are you trying to accomplish with that?  Do you just mean to do `var post = rows;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]` is produced because `var post = rows[];` is invalid. When it gets to the `[` the next thing it expects is a number ([or string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)) that represents the index of the item in the array.

For example, if you change it to `var post = rows[0];` you'll get the first element in the array.

Comment: Technically, it expects a String or something that can be stringified.

Comment: You're right, it does :) thanks - i've updated my answer